# R does not show special characters coming from json source

Tags: json, r, windows, utf-8, jsonlite

a little bit about the background.
I pull data from an API that supplies public transportation data. It returns the result in json format, which I process with the library 'jsonlite'.

```
 resp <- GET(url = url)


  resp_char <- rawToChar(resp$content)
  parsed <- fromJSON(resp_char, flatten = T)

  parsed.df <- do.call(what = "rbind", args = lapply(parsed[1], as.data.frame))
```

The problem is, in the result there are no special characters.

I am working on a Windows Server 2012 machine and my language settings in R look like this:

```
    > Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
```

Example:

```
    > df$direction
"U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)" 
"U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)" 
"U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)"              
"U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)" 
"MÃ¤rkisches Viertel, Wilhelmsruher Damm"
```

The expected result for the fifth result is "Märkisches Viertel, Wilhelmsruher Damm"

After that I looked in the actual encoding.

```
> Encoding(df$direction)
   [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"
```

In my opinion this looks good so far, but nevertheless I cannot see special characters.

I appreciate any suggestions and ideas on the subject.

Regards

Comment: have you tried this function ```iconv```?

Comment: Yes I tried. That is the result > iconv(tmpStore2$direction,to ="UTF8")
   [1] "U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)"                 "U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)"                      "U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)"                
   [4] "U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)"                      "MÃƒÂ¤rkisches Viertel, Wilhelmsruher Damm"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So finally I got it.
Thanks to @parth, it has led me to the right answer. 
I used Encoding before my fromJSON statement and that worked for me.

```
  resp <- GET(url = url)

  resp_char <- rawToChar(resp$content)
  Encoding(resp_char) <- "UTF-8"
  parsed <- fromJSON(resp_char, flatten = T)

  parsed.df <- do.call(what = "rbind", args = lapply(parsed[1], as.data.frame))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the dataframe

`df<-data.frame(direction=c("U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)","U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)","U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)","U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)","MÃ¤rkisches Viertel, Wilhelmsruher Damm"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

```
> df
                                direction
1               U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)
2                    U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)
3               U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)
4                    U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)
5 MÃ¤rkisches Viertel, Wilhelmsruher Damm
```

Now, just change the encoding of entire `df$direction` column as

```
Encoding(df$direction) <- "UTF-8"
```

which fixes the issue

```
> df
                               direction
1              U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)
2                   U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)
3              U Alt-Mariendorf (Berlin)
4                   U Alt-Tegel (Berlin)
5 Märkisches Viertel, Wilhelmsruher Damm
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is just working in your example. The difference ist, that my Dataframe already is UTF-8 encoded (see above). Your code is in Latin1 and then it works.. (converting my dataframe in latin1 and back to utf-8 does not work)